# Trying to make a transaction history

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys im trying to make a transaction history getting the details of course form the database.

The details show perfect when user have and active subscription but when the suscription expire do not show anything and just show 1 row.

I want to show in history obviosly all transactions active or expired. Here is my code.

Active =1 expired =0 just for your knowledge

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM `subscriptions` WHERE `username` = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
     if ($row['active'] == 1)
     {
         $status    = "Active";
         $transid   = $row['txn_id'];
         $transdate = date('F j, Y',strtotime($row['date']));
         $subid     = $row['id'];
         $payment   = $row['payment'];
     }
     else 
     {
         $status    = "Expired";
         $transid   = $row['txn_id'];
         $transdate = date('F j, Y',strtotime($row['date']));
         $subid     = $row['id'];
         $payment   = $row['payment'];
     }
}
?>
```

I use the if and else to show if active or expired in status.

My html code

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-vcenter">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">ID</th>
                <th class="text-center">PRODUCT</th>
                <th class="text-center">STATUS</th>
                <th class="text-center">DATE</th>
                <th class="text-center">PAYMENT</th>
                <th class="text-center">TRANSACTION ID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>


        <?php
        echo'    
        <tbody class="text-center">

            <tr>
                <td>'.$subid.'</td>
                <td>'.$package.'</td>
                <td>'.$status.'</td>
                <td>'.$transdate.'</td>
                <td>'.$payment.'</td>
                <td>'.$transid.'</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>';
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Some caps here for example i want to show this always the subscription still active or not because obviously it's a history

[active subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afu1e.png)
the problem is that if the user subscription expire do not show in history and only show 1 the last

here when expire
[expired subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF3bm.png)
and

Comment: can you print `mysqli_num_rows($result)` & check the output how much rows it currently has

Comment: Also where are you displaying this....show the html code as well

Comment: Please include some sample data.  I see no obvious problem, other than you should be using prepared statements.

Comment: Are you using a specific CMS or framework? OR this is just plain PHP and a custom MySQL DB?

Comment: @AgamBanga i update the post with code and caps

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i updated

Comment: @timo it's a custom script made by me from scratch it's a simple web just php, bootstrap and mysql

Comment: First of all, insert the values into an array & the you should use the `loop` to create the table rows

Comment: I have knowledge in PHP but sometimes I stay locked in things that maybe are easy

Comment: @AgamBanga can you give me an example

Comment: @JuanMontes i have added a sample. Take a look at that

Comment: You might win a few friends by upvoting and:or accepting some answers.

Comment: yes thanks for remember @Strawberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initially put the database values to an `array`

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM subscriptions sub LEFT JOIN package pack ON (pack.id=sub.package) WHERE sub.username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$tableArray = array();
$counter = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
     $tableArray[$counter]['status'] = $row['active'] == 1 ? 'Active' : 'Expired';
     $tableArray[$counter]['transid'] = $row['txn_id'];
     $tableArray[$counter]['transdate'] = date('F j, Y',strtotime($row['date']));
     $tableArray[$counter]['subid'] = $row['id'];
     $tableArray[$counter]['payment'] = $row['payment'];
     $counter++;
}
?>
```

Now access this array into the html part & iterate over it via `foreach`

**HTML**

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-vcenter">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">ID</th>
                <th class="text-center">PRODUCT</th>
                <th class="text-center">STATUS</th>
                <th class="text-center">DATE</th>
                <th class="text-center">PAYMENT</th>
                <th class="text-center">TRANSACTION ID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="text-center">
            <?php foreach($tableArray as $row) {?>
            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['package'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['status'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['transdate'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['payment'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['transid'] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

In the HTML, `$row['package']` will be undefined, you need to fetch it from database as well if that is the field in your database. Your question didn't have this field. Please include it as well

Comment: So it works perfect only for some reason does not show the id of each transaction and how can I do to show the product because in the subscription table is the column package but this only contains the package id the product name is in the Table packages how do I display it if they are from different tables?

Comment: Done i fixed the id problem but if u can help me with the package i really appreciate that

Comment: you need to use the `LEFT JOIN` to get the package name

Comment: You need to JOIN the package table in the SELECT statement. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: @AgamBanga let me know if this are well i'm a noob on mysql xD

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM `subscriptions` as 'subs' Left Join `package` as 'packs' WHERE `subs.username` = '$username' AND `packs.package` = 'subs.package'";

Comment: @JuanMontes updated the query. Check the join conditions `pack.id=sub.package`. In this `pack.id` is the primary key of package table & `sub.package` is the foreign key

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM `subscriptions` WHERE `username` = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$tableArray = array();
$counter = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $pack = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `packages` WHERE `id` = '$row[package]'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
                                            while ($packname = mysqli_fetch_array($pack)) {
                                               $packs = $packname['name'];
                                            }

Comment: I could do it that way

Comment: @JuanMontes you should't execute queries in loop unless its required essentially. The above scenario doesn't require the query in loop. You should try to use the join instead of looping query as there will be huge performance difference between the two

Answer (score 1):

My version :)

**PHP**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `subscriptions` WHERE `username` = ?";
$queryStmt = $con->prepare( $query );

if ( $queryStmt )
{
    $queryStmt->bind_param( "s", $username ); // <-- This prevents SQL injection and may be handy for executing the query several time more efficiently
    $queryStmt->execute();
    $queryStmt->bind_result( $active, $transid, $date, $subid, $payment, $package ); // <-- the order must match the order of the fields in the $query

    $rows = []; // <-- load here the content fo the DB rows
    while( $queryStmt->fetch() )
    {
        // Transform needed variables

        $status = ( $active == 1 ) ? "Active" : "Expired";
        $transdate = date( 'F j, Y', strtotime( $date ) );

        $rows[] = compact( 'satus', 'transid', 'transdate', 'subid', 'payment', 'package' );
    }

    $queryStmt->close();
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-vcenter">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">ID</th>
            <th class="text-center">PRODUCT</th>
            <th class="text-center">STATUS</th>
            <th class="text-center">DATE</th>
            <th class="text-center">PAYMENT</th>
            <th class="text-center">TRANSACTION ID</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="text-center">
        <?php foreach( $rows as $row ) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['subid'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['package'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['status'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['transdate'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['payment'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['transid'] ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Good to know. :) Please, start preparing your queries, it's good practice and will avoid you some bad headaches one day. ;)